# Is the solution of $e^x \log(x)=1$ transcendental?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Let $u$ be the solution of the equation $$e^x \log(x)=1$$

Is $u$ rational, irrational algebraic or transcendental?

$u$ seems to be transcendental, but I cannot prove it.

Perhaps, someone has an idea.

Comment: I apologize for the format, but this website uses an annoying filter for "quality standards". It seems that a question is not allowed to be short and direct. Do not ask me why ...

Comment: The numerical value of u is 1.30979 95858 04150 47767 , rounded to 20 digits.

Comment: Tabulated to 99 digits at http://oeis.org/A201942/b201942.txt (but with no helpful information)

Comment: I calculated u to 100 000 digits with PARI. Looking at the continued fraction, brought me to the conjecture, that u is transcendental.

Comment: The theorems of gelfond-schneider and lindemann-weierstrass do not seem to help.

Comment: What is it about the continued fraction that you take to distinguish transcendentals from algebraic irrationals? Next to nothing is known about about the continued fraction of, say, $\root3\of2$.

Comment: The vector of the convergents has high numbers. Of course, this does not proof anything.

Comment: How high? Higher than for $\root3\of5$?