# Irrationality/Transcendentality of values of $e^{e^x}$

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

1) Is $e^{e^x}$ irrational for all rational $x$?

It is known that $e^x$ is transcendental for every nonzero algebraic $x$.
But this dos not help here because for transcedental $x$, $e^x$ can be
rational.

2) Is $e^{e^x}$ transcendental for all algebraic $x$?

This would imply 1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see you have also asked similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522342/is-the-solution-of-ex-logx-1-transcendental). It is a bit old, but nevertheless I believe I have results that might interest you, especially the later one.

---

*Claim:* $[2]$ is true, conditionally on [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture)

*Proof:* Specifically, *Schanuel's conjecture* states that

$$\text{trdeg}_{\mathbb{Q}} \,\! \mathbb{Q}\left(x_1, x_2, \cdots x_n, e^{x_1}, e^{x_2}, \cdots , e^{x_n}\right) \geq n$$

for $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \in \mathbb{C}$. One can verify that $(x_1 , x_2) = (e^x, 1)$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, thus the above gives $\left(e^x, e^{e^x}\right)$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraically independent pair and since $e^x$ for $x \in \mathbb{\bar Q}$ is transcendental, we have transcendence of $e^{e^x}$. $\blacksquare$

*Claim:* At least one of $\large e^{e^x}, e^{e^{2x}}$ and $\large e^{e^{3x}}$ is transcendental

*Proof:* This can be concluded from the lines of the proof of *Schneider's conjecture* done in [*Brownawell$(1974)$*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X74900055). In general, it has been proved (unconditionally, in the same paper) that for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C} \! \setminus \!\!\mathbb{Q}$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ if $e^{\alpha}, e^{\alpha \gamma} \in \mathbb{\bar Q}$ then at least two of

$$\large \alpha, \beta, \gamma, e^{\beta\gamma}, e^{\alpha\beta\gamma}$$

are $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraically independent. The claim is then proved by setting $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = e^{x}$ $\blacksquare$

*Note:*

- $[1]$ in general is wide open currently, as far as I know. I recall though that transcendence of power towers of polynomials of $e$ over $\bar Q$ holds with some weaker condition than Schanuel. I'll link it to here as soon as I remember.