# A tower of irrationals?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Set $x_0:=1$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ set $x_n:=2^{\frac{1}{2}x_{n-1}}$, so
$$x_1=\sqrt{2},\; x_2=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}, x_3=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}},\ldots$$
Undoubtedly the $x_n$ are irrational for all $n\in\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2,\ldots\}$. (How) can we prove that?

Comment: Definitely x_{0} is rational but I feel that all following terms are irrational. Try proving that by induction.

Comment: @Deepak I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Deepak It's not clear to me that Gelfond-Schneider can get us past $n = 2$; $x_3$ is an algebraic raised to a transcendental power, which could possibly be rational (see, for example, $2^{\log_2(3)}$).

Comment: @Reese You are correct. The theorem fails quickly here. I overlooked that.

Comment: @Rohan: Have _you_ tried proving it by induction? Do you have any reason to think it might work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Undoubtedly the $x_n$ are irrational for all $n∈N={1,2,…}$*

The proof of that statement would earn you a fair amount of fame, since the irrationality of $x_n$ for $n>2$ is still an open problem.

Indeed, one can use the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) to prove that $\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2}$ is transcendental:

> **Theorem (Gelfond-Schneider).** If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a ≠ 0, a ≠ 1$, and $b$ irrational, then any value of $a^b$ is a
>   transcendental number.

However, currently we have no tools to assess the irrationality of numbers such as $\sqrt 2^{{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}}$ where the exponent is transcendental.

There exist however other related numbers whose rationality is known, for instance the infinite tower

$$
\sqrt 2^{{{\sqrt 2}^{{\sqrt 2}^{\ldots}}}} = \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{4}^{{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{4}}^\ldots} = 2,
$$

which is the value of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$. In particular, we have the following lemma.

> **Lemma.** Let $n$ be a positive integer different than $1$, $2$ and $4$. Then the infinite power tower 
>   $$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{n}^{{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{n}}^\ldots}$$
>   is transcendental.

In particular, 
$$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{3}^{{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{3}}^\ldots}$$
is a transcendental number.

---

Finally, I give the following interesting reference on infinite power towers:

Mladen V-M, Some Results On Infinite Power Towers, *Notes on Number Theory and Discrete Mathematics* (2010), **3**, 18-24.

It is freely accessible at:

http://www.nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-16/NNTDM-16-3-18-24.pdf